# Including graph using tikz causes not including bibliography file

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, r

I am experiencing problems using package tikz. 
I have produced a graph in R and want to include it in my tex file using package tikz. After I include the the tex  file with graph in myfile.tex with command `\include{histogram}`, my bibliography.tex file is not included. If I remove the `\include{graph}` command in `myfile.tex`, the bibliography is included again. 
Does anybody know why this is happening?

the preambule in myfile.tex is

```
\documentclass[titlepage,a4paper,oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{lmodern} %lmodern nefungovalo bold kapitalky
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[top=30mm , bottom=30mm , left=35mm , right=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{icomma} %desetinna carka bez mezery

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markright{\large{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter. \ #1}}}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}


\usepackage{setspace}

\newcommand{\txtsource}[1]{\texttt{\textit{#1}}}
\setcounter{topnumber}{8}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{8}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{8}



\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\large}

\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\large}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength {\parskip }{6pt}
\setlength {\parindent }{1cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}\normalsize

\DeclareQuoteStyle{czech} 
{\quotedblbase}
 {\textquotedblright}
  [0.05em]
  {\textquoteleft}
{\textquoteright}
```

Thanks!

Comment: probably you should be using `\input` not `\include` but without seeing the file `histogram.tex`  and the context in which you are including it into the document it is hard to say. What error do you get from TeX?

Comment: Do you have `\end{document}` inside `histogram.tex`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The problem was with my bibliography but now I am experience that tikz ignores the special signs like 'č' that are typical for my language. Do I need any other package to be included or where can be the problem?